# Why are my service properties not being updated?

Tags: angularjs

In my view I'm binding to a service property, that service property is bound to another service property.

Trouble is, neither service property is being updated when I change it in the view. Can any one shed any light please?

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/D0YMzD?p=preview

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', 'serviceOne', function($scope, serviceOne) {

    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.val = serviceOne.val;

    $scope.$watch(function() {
      return ctrl.val;
    }, function() {
      console.log('ctrl says val=' + ctrl.val);
    }, true);

}]);
```

serviceOne:

```
myApp.service('serviceOne', ['serviceTwo', '$rootScope', function (serviceTwo, $rootScope) {

    var sOne = this;

    sOne.val = serviceTwo.val;

    $rootScope.$watch(function() {
        return sOne.val;
    }, function() {
        console.log('sOne says val=' + sOne.val);
    }, true);

}]);
```

serviceTwo:

```
myApp.service('serviceTwo', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

    var sTwo = this;

    sTwo.val = "hello";

    $rootScope.$watch(function() {
        return sTwo.val;
    }, function() {
        console.log('sTwo says val=' + sTwo.val);
    }, true);

}]);
```

Comment: where you update your value to service ?

Comment: First place why you want two services? why don't have two variable in single service if its necessary..

Comment: serviceOne is an overarching service that injects a number of different services with common APIs and performs operations on their models. The example I posted was the bare bones of what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an "always have a dot in your model" problem. You're passing strings, not object references. This works:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', 'serviceOne', function($scope, serviceOne) {

    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.val = serviceOne.val;

    $scope.$watch(function() {
      return ctrl.val;
    }, function() {
      console.log('ctrl says val=' + ctrl.val.s);
    }, true);

}]);

myApp.service('serviceOne', ['serviceTwo', '$rootScope', function (serviceTwo, $rootScope) {

  var sOne = this;

  sOne.val = serviceTwo.val;

  $rootScope.$watch(function() {
    return sOne.val.s;
  }, function() {
    console.log('sOne says val=' + sOne.val.s);
  }, true);

}]);

myApp.service('serviceTwo', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

  var sTwo = this;

  sTwo.val = { s: "hello" };

  $rootScope.$watch(function() {
    return sTwo.val.s;
  }, function() {
    console.log('sTwo says val=' + sTwo.val.s);
  }, true);

}]);
```

And appropriate change in your template:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl as ctrl">
      <input ng-model="ctrl.val.s"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: Arghhh, can't believe I got caught by this! :)

I've posted a [plunker](http://bit.ly/1EESd1S) that is closer to my actual app, and it's still causing problems, I think it might be related but can't see what the problem is. The second service is, once again, not getting updated. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Typo on my part, please ignore the last comment!